# Conditional Regex with lookarounds

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm attempting to write regex that captures the values of data in key/value pair format.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to find exactly what I needed  but I suspect it has to do with conditional look arounds.  I'm also not sure this is the best solution.

The key/value pair will look like the following:

- `... source=<value> ...` -- No quotes/spaces
- `... source="<value with spaces>" ...` -- quotes with spaces
- `... source="<value>" ...` -- quotes with no spaces

I'm white listing characters with the expression `\bsource(::|=)([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\*\"\:\.\/]+)`.  If there are spaces in the value then the first word is captured and nothing after or if I whitelist spaces then I capture more than needed.  To match the value while avoiding the surrounding double quotes would be awesome too!

Data samples:

```
... source="source name with quotes - special characters also" ...

... source=source_name_without_quotes_with_special-characters* ...

... source="source_name_with_quotes_no_spaces-*" ...
```

Any assistance or guidance would be extremely helpful, thanks in advance!

~Tensore

Comment: You can use `\bsource(::|=)("[^"]*"|\S+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *conditional expression* would look like this

```
\bsource(?::|=)(")?(?(1)(?P<value1>[^"]+)"|(?P<value2>\S+))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WpilXb/1).

---

But you do not really need it here, use a simple alternation instead:

```
\bsource(?::|=)(?:"(?P<value1>[^"]+)"|(?P<value2>\S+))
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ZSxmKD/1).

---

You could even use a *branch reset* for the same name of the group:

```
\bsource(?::|=)(?|"(?P<value>[^"]+)"|(?P<value>\S+))
```

See [**the last demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CyWDyg/1/).

Comment: Scholar and a gentleperson!  Thanks!